# Python IF conditions 1, 2, and 3 are valid THEN replace with 0, ELSE if not valid replace with other variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with 3 variables: 1 date variable (yyyy-mm-dd), 1 numeric variable, and 1 boolean variable (true/false)

The conditions I want to apply are that IF month = 12 and day = 24 (so Christmas) and Boolean = True, then I want Numeric = 0. Else, I want Numeric to be what it was.

I've seen many similar questions but none of them wants the numeric variable to be the same in case the condition doesn't apply.

Comment: Have a look at `np.where`. When asking a question it is best to provide sample input data, the expected output and what you've tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *assume* you have a pandas `DataFrame` with some data, like the following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2018-12-24',1,True],
                        ['2018-12-25',2,False],
                        ['2019-12-24',3,True],
                        ['2019-12-25',4,False],
                        ['2020-12-24',5,False],
                        ['2020-12-25',6,False]], columns=['d','n','b'])
df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['d'])
```

i.e. `print(df)` will output:

```
     d        n    b
0 2018-12-24  1   True
1 2018-12-25  2  False
2 2019-12-24  3   True
3 2019-12-25  4  False
4 2020-12-24  5  False
5 2020-12-25  6  False
```

If this is indeed the case, then *consider simply overwriting some entries* with `0`:

```py
df.loc[(df['d'].dt.day == 24) & (df['d'].dt.month == 12) & df['b'], 'n'] = 0
```

...and now `print(df)` outputs:

```
     d        n    b
0 2018-12-24  0   True
1 2018-12-25  2  False
2 2019-12-24  0   True
3 2019-12-25  4  False
4 2020-12-24  5  False
5 2020-12-25  6  False
```

Comment: Your example works, and it is what I have, but it doesn't work on my data! Odd, let me try to just restart the kernel and maybe it'll work for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: pay *extra care* to the parentheses above! (namely in the important command `df.loc[(...) & (...) & (...), 'n'] = 0`)

Comment: It turned out that my boolean was in fact a categorical binary variable, and when I changed it back to boolean it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would help if you showed us some code, but do you mean something like this?

```
if month == 12 and day == 24 and Boolean == True:
    numeric = 0
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Ok so "pass" is the equivalent of "let the numeric be what it already is"?

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't do the trick:

Ok so "pass" is the equivalent of "let the numeric be what it already is"?

I've tried this, the code works but my data is not what I want it to be: 
conditions = [
    (df['Boolean'] == 'TRUE'), (df['Date'].dt.day == 24) & (df['Date'].dt.month == 12)
    ]

values = [0, df['Numeric']]

df['Numeric'] = np.select(conditions, values)

Comment: Pass is just a placeholder statement that doesn't do anything. You could just remove the "else" portion of the statement entirely, but I think it's better to leave it to actually show that you don't want to do anything if the above statement is not True.

Comment: Causes this error...

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().